Movie about three candidates running for President? Electoral college
I'm looking for an American movie - maybe in black and white.  I think it's probably from the 1950s or 1960s.
It's about three men running for President (or possibly as one party's nominee).  We have the good guy - the hero we follow - who's leading the polls... We have the bad guy - who's second in the polls...  And we have the third guy - who doesn't stand a chance - but is basically a good guy.
I'm not sure, but I think most of the movie actually take place during the day of the Electoral college...  The good guy have won the election, with the bad guy on second place.  Just before the electoral vote, the bad guy threatens to reveal some sort of scandal about the good guy - which will not only destroy his presidency, but also his family... unless he step down.
The good guy do step down, but he instructs his electors to give their votes to the third candidates instead of him - so the third candidate ends up beating the bad guy and becomes President.
Does this sounds familiar to anybody?

The Best Man (1964) with Henry Fonda, Cliff Robertson & Lee Tracey

William Russell (Fonda) and Joe Cantwell (Robertson) are the two leading candidates for the presidential nomination of an unspecified political party. Both have potentially fatal vulnerabilities. Russell is a principled intellectual. 
A sexual indiscretion has alienated his wife Alice (Margaret Leighton). In addition, he has a past nervous breakdown to live down. Cantwell  portrays himself as a populist "man of the people," and patriotic anti-comunist campaigning to end "the missile gap". Cantwell is a ruthless opportunist, willing to go to any lengths to get the nomination.

Wikipedia Link

After the first ballot, Russell arranges to meet Cantwell privately but when Bascomb is confronted face-to-face by Cantwell, he refutes his slander. Russell threatens to use the allegation anyway, but Cantwell knows Russell does not have the stomach for tactics that dirty. As the rounds of balloting continue, it becomes obvious neither man has enough votes. Cantwell offers Russell second spot on his ticket but Russell shocks him by throwing his support behind the low-profile Merwin. It puts an end to both their chances but unites the party around an electable candidate.


